# Trouble in SVG Sales Sum and Average Display

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, measure

_Hi, I have worked on an SVG example in which I chose to display the sum of sales and the total average sales for both the current and previous year.
However, I am struggling with the current sales year average in the table, which is incorrect, even though it appears correct in a card. I can't figure out why?
Furthermore, the average bar for the current year appears to be okay, but not the one for the previous year...
Can someone help me ? Thanks in advance for your time.
[Here is the link of my pbix file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv9BYrpfxnOguSDZMC?e=fEhOhF)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my code ;).

You have a filter on the table which is why you're seeing a different figure. Remove the filter and you'll see the correct figure.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know you are the master behind... ;) Actually, the average calculation includes an ALLSELECTED ( Data[Country] ), [Sales CY] ) instruction, so I don't understand why the calculation is not thus updated with the Country filter ? Can you help me also with the PY average bar ? Many Thanks...

Comment: ALLSELECTED() won't remove the visual filter you have applied. If you need help with something else, it best to ask a new dedicated question with the details of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll post another one.